# Entropy never decreases but change can be negative

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Often called entropy postulate that in an irreversible process entropy always increases, it never decreases.

Change in entropy is defined as,

$$\Delta{S}=Q/T$$

When Q is negative change in entropy becomes negative. Does this connote that process is reversible and can happen the other way round?

Comment: The *total* entropy will always increase or not change. The entropy of a sub-system can decrease, but for other it will at the same time increase.

Comment: The point is that the TOTAL entropy increases in an irreversible process, so you have to take the sum of the variation of entropy of the system and the surrounding.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that the law of increasing entropy applies to isolated, closed systems, yes, negative entropy means reversible process is at work, which can be reversed given enough heat.

A good example is precipitation. When crystals precipitate from a liquid , the crystals themselves have lower entropy than when their mass was in the liquid, but the total entropy increases as heat is released to the rest of the liquid environment in precipitation. The crystals will melt if enough heat is supplied.

Another is rain: air gets warmer when it rains, i.e. when humidity precipitates into drops. Water will evaporate when heated.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics says that the total entropy change in an isolated system is $\geq 0$ for any permissible real process.

The entropy change $\Delta S_{A\rightarrow B}= S_{B}-S_{A}$ in a quasistatic process in which the total isolated system transitions from a state $A$ to $B$, is just the difference of the entropy values at those two states $A$ and $B$, because entropy is a state function.

A process is called reversible if both the quasistatic transition from $A$ to $B$, and the reverse quasistatic transition from $B$ to $A$ is permissible. Which is to say, we require both $S_{A}-S_{B}\geq 0$ and $S_{B}-S_{A}\geq 0$, that is, $\Delta S_{A\rightarrow B}=\Delta S_{B\rightarrow A}=0$.

Pertaining to your question, the entropy of the isolated total system is additive over it's constituent parts, and it may so happen that we have a permissible transition of the total isolated system from one state to another, with the total entropy change of the total isolated system non negative, but where the entropy change within the particular subsystem is negative, only to be compensated by the greater positive entropy change in the other sub parts of the total system.

This happens, as you point out, when you have heat flowing out of a particular subsystem at greater temperature, in which part the entropy decreases; while a subsystem at lower temperature gains the heat, where the entropy change is actually greater in magnitude.

The fact that you may have a process in which a subsystem loses entropy, is not relevant to whether the total change in the total system is reversible; you may just as well have a reversible process in which the entropy change in all the subparts of the system is exactly 0. Consider a simple container of ideal gas enclosed by adiabatic walls. Then any subpart of the ideal gas has net entropy change 0, in a quasistatic adiabatic process.

Comment: Small observations: let's not call it "entropy principle": it is not a principle, it is a consequence of the Clausius inequality. Also, since $S$ is a state function, $\Delta S_{AB}$ *always* depends only on the states $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Agree that $S_{AB}$ is a state function. I try to write that more clearly now. Also edited the first line to change "entropy principle" to 2nd Law of Thermodynamics. It is important to realise that the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics is equivalent to the Clausius inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of $\Delta S$ is only valid for an *isothermal, reversible* process.

We start from the Clausius inequality,

$$\Delta S_{AB} \geq \int_A^B \frac{\delta Q} T\tag{1}$$

where the equal sign refers to a reversible transformation. If the system is isolated, $\delta Q=0$, therefore we obtain

$$\Delta S \geq 0$$

i.e. : *in a generic transformation of an **isolated** system, the change in entropy is always greater or equal to zero, and it is zero only if the transformation is reversible*.

Now, if $T=const.$ (isothermal process), we obtain from $(1)$:

$$\Delta S_{AB} \geq \frac 1 T \int_A^B \delta Q = \frac Q T $$

and if the process is *reversible*, we get

$$\Delta S = \frac Q T$$

However, we are clearly not considering an isolated system, because for an isolated system $\delta Q=0$.

So, the apparent contradiction came from the wrong assumption that $\Delta S = Q/T$ is valid for a generic transformation.